# Permission denied trying to save python-docx file on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-docx

I want to save a **python-docx** document to a directory with 777 privileges on Ubuntu, but I get this error: `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'media/Rooming Grand Oasis Cancun 2018-11-01-2018-11-30.docx'`.

This is the code of the **Django Rest Framework** view:

```
def get_hotel_document(self, request, start_date, end_date, confirmed, hotel, bookings):
    from django.core.files import File
    from django.urls import reverse
    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import Inches, Pt

    document = Document()

    section = document.sections[-1]
    section.left_margin = Inches(0.5)
    section.right_margin = Inches(0.5)

    style = document.styles['Normal']
    font = style.font
    font.name ='Arial'
    font.size = Pt(10)

    ... more code ...

    file_name = "media/Rooming {} {}-{}.docx".format(hotel, start_date, end_date)
    document.save(file_name)

    return file_name
```

Here you can see the permissions of the directory:

[image]

The error rises when calling `document.save(file_name)`.

Comment: are you sure that media is the directory you are trying to write into? `media/Rooming Grand Oasis Cancun 2018-11-01-2018-11-30.docx` is a relative path ... what is it relativeto if you run your code?

Comment: Does the file already exist in the folder? It might not have the right permissions there, even though the parent folder has.

Comment: What user is the django code running as?